# Avoiding infinite useEffect loop while reflecting state change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create an app where the user can click on a category and it will set the `displayWork` array to the value of the category and thus display the items in that array.

I have all of the work stored in an array

```
 const [workList, setWorkList] = useState([
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/1.jfif", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "plumbing", image: "./images/2.jfif", type: "plumbing" },
    { title: "Other 3", image: "./images/3.png", type: "other3" },
    { title: "Other 4", image: "./images/3.png", type: "other4" },
  ]);
```

and then I have my `displayWork` mapped to the page, I plan on changing it through using array.filter()

```
let filteredWork = workList.filter(function (work) {
      return work.type === catagory;
    });
```

then I have a row of categories like this to set the parameters of the filter

```
 <div className="col-sm-2  workCatagory" onClick={() => setCatagory("landscaping")}>
          Land Scaping
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-2 workCatagory" onClick={() => setCatagory("plumbing")}>
          plumbing
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-2 workCatagory" onClick={() => setCatagory("other3")}>
          test3
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-2 workCatagory" onClick={() => setCatagory("other4")}>
          Test4
        </div>
```

And then I am setting the `displayWork` to the value of the filtered array like so:

```
 <div className="row workBars" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
 const handleClick = () => {
setDisplayWork(filteredWork)
 }
```

The problem with this approach is the change is not reflected immediately upon clicking the button.  Using this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) I was able to fix this

```
useEffect(() => {
      handleClick()
    }, [handleClick])
```

But I ran into an error message and the page crashing on me very often, I cannot get the state to update immediately without also creating an infinite loop. A link to my full page is here [github](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/Curb-Appeal/blob/main/src/pages/work.js) I appreciate any advice you may have

Comment: A stackblitz or codesandbox would help us to solve it easily.

Comment: Here you are https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-khayyam-fjktw?file=/src/pages/work.js

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by "the change is not reflected immediately upon clicking the button". Maybe there is a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use non-state variables to dependencies. So you need to wrap it into `useMemo`, `useCallback` to avoid infinitive loop

```
const filteredWork = useMemo(
  () =>
    workList.filter(function (work) {
      return work.type === catagory;
    }),
  [workList, category],
);

const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
  setDisplayWork(filteredWork);
}, [setDisplayWork, filteredWork]);
```

Comment: `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` Do you know why it's giving me this error?

Comment: `> 53 | const handleClick = useCallBack(() => {`

Comment: Where do you import useCallback?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: It looks like I just had a typo,  this is working now. Thank you, I will study these 2 hooks so i can learn in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the architecture of the component.

Instead of calling two functions (setCategory and handleClick) for a single action is not a good idea.

So I added an useEffect hook, which gets triggered whenever the category is changed. In this way, the whole execution will be somehow synchronous.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";

import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
export const Work = () => {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
  const [workList, setWorkList] = useState([
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/1.jfif", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/1.jfif", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/1.jfif", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/1.jfif", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/1.jfif", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/1.jfif", type: "landscaping" },

    { title: "plumbing", image: "./images/2.jfif", type: "plumbing" },
    { title: "plumbing", image: "./images/2.jfif", type: "plumbing" },
    { title: "plumbing", image: "./images/2.jfif", type: "plumbing" },
    { title: "plumbing", image: "./images/2.jfif", type: "plumbing" },
    { title: "plumbing", image: "./images/2.jfif", type: "plumbing" },
    { title: "plumbing", image: "./images/2.jfif", type: "plumbing" },
    { title: "plumbing", image: "./images/2.jfif", type: "plumbing" },
    { title: "plumbing", image: "./images/2.jfif", type: "plumbing" },

    { title: "Other 3", image: "./images/3.png", type: "other3" },
    { title: "Other 4", image: "./images/3.png", type: "other4" },
  ]);
  const [displayWork, setDisplayWork] = useState([
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/test.png", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/test.png", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/test.png", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/test.png", type: "landscaping" },
    { title: "aaa", image: "./images/test.png", type: "landscaping" },
  ]);
  const [catagory, setCatagory] = useState("Select a catagory");

  
    //let newArray = workList.filter(workList.type.includes(catagory))
  
    
  
const Animation = () => {
console.log('woo')
}

  useEffect(() => {
    let filteredWork = workList.filter(function (work) {
      return work.type === catagory;
    });
    setDisplayWork(filteredWork);
  }, [catagory, workList]);
  

  return (
    <div className="workPage" id="workPage">
      <h1 className="text-center">Here's what we can do</h1>
      <div className="row workBars">
        <div className="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div className="col-sm-2  workCatagory" onClick={() => setCatagory("landscaping")}>
          Land Scaping
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-2 workCatagory" onClick={() => setCatagory("plumbing")}>
          plumbing
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-2 workCatagory" onClick={() => setCatagory("other3")}>
          test3
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-2 workCatagory" onClick={() => setCatagory("other4")}>
          Test4
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1> {catagory}</h1>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-2"></div>
        {displayWork.map((displayWork) => (
          <div className="col-sm-4">
            {" "}
            <br />
            <p>{displayWork.title}</p>
            <img
              src={displayWork.image}
              alt={displayWork.name}
              className="img-fluid workImage"
            ></img>
          </div>
        ))}
        <div className="col-sm-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```